# How to change the product key of SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currently using SQL server 2008 R2 Standard edition in a Cluster. During the initial installation I used the product key which was automatically bonded with the setup DVD. Now I have a need to change the product key, keeping the same edition, without reinstalling SQL server.

I have tried the `Maintenance->Edition Upgrade` option from SQL Installer Center but no luck. Please let me know if there is any alternative way to change the product key.

Comment: What's the reason that you are changing the key? As long as the edition is correct and you actually own the license that's all that matters.

Comment: The customer wants us to update the proper license keys obtain for the servers ..hence I am curious to update the license keys

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by 'no luck' as that is the main method of changing the CD-key for SQL, but you can also try command line "Setup.exe /q /ACTION=editionupgrade /INSTANCENAME= /PID=" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS"

-source [http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/06/upgrade-sql-server-edition-or-change.html]

You cannot use these methods to downgrade if you are looking to go that route. If it is a current cluster, you should be able to update the key on one node and then trigger a failover to automatically update the other node(s).

Comment: John..thanks for your reply..I have used the above method but it didn't worked for me since my edition will remain same as standard.. If you have any other workarounds please let me know..however if nothing works then its simple just reinstall SQL server with new license key :-)